# Ошибка в php Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, ооп

Делаю парсер который из https://habrahabr.ru будет парсить последний пост в каждом из самостоятельно заданных хабов.

Ошибка :

> Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Parser\class.php on line 44

Это класс использующийся для этого:

```
class Parser {
        public $hubs = array(
            'infosecurity'=>"https://habrahabr.ru/hub/infosecurity/",
            'programming' =>"https://habrahabr.ru/hub/programming/",
            'webdev'=>"https://habrahabr.ru/hub/webdev/",
            'linux'=>"https://habrahabr.ru/hub/linux/",
            'algorithms'=>"https://habrahabr.ru/hub/algorithms/"
            ); 
        public $links = array(
            'infosecurity' => "",
            'programming' => "",
            'webdev' => "",
            'linux' => "",
            'algorithms' =>""
            );
        public $headers = array(
            'infosecurity' => "",
            'programming' => "",
            'webdev' => "",
            'linux' => "",
            'algorithms' =>""
            );
        public $texts = array(
            'infosecurity' => "",
            'programming' => "",
            'webdev' => "",
            'linux' => "",
            'algorithms' =>""
            );

        //функция принимает аргументы страницу и тэг(класс), тип возвр значения и возвращает содержимое тэга
        public function get_article_link($page_link, $tag, $type) {
            $html = get_curl($page_link);//получаем html 
            $dom = str_get_html($html);// создает для каждого тэга свой обьект
            $article = $dom->find($tag);//ссылка на статью
            return $article[0]->$type.'<br>';            
        }
        public function get_content($page_link, $tag, $type) {
            $html = get_curl($page_link);//получаем html 
            $dom = str_get_html($html);// создает для каждого тэга свой обьект
            $article = $dom->find($tag);//ссылка на статью
            //var_dump($article);
            return  $article[0]->$type.'<br>';   // строка ошибки           
        }
    }
```

При обращении к методам класса и передачи им параметра ссылки на статьи возникает упомянутая ошибка

```
foreach ($Habr->links as $key => $value) {

       // Обрезаем содержимое до первого "/" чтобы получить заголовок
//        
        $title =  $Habr ->get_content($Habr->links["$key"], 'title', 'plaintext');    
        $str = strpos($title, "/");
        $title = substr($title, 0, $str);
        $Habr->headers[$key] = $title;
        //Выводим заголовок 
        echo "<br><b>TITLE : </b><br>".$title."<br>";

        //выводим текст статьи 

        $text = $Habr ->get_content($Habr->links[$key], '.post__text', 'plaintext');
        $Habr->texts[$key] = $text;
        echo "<b>TEXT OF PAGE:<br></b>".$Habr->texts[$key]."<br>";         
        }
```

Ошибка в выражении `$Habr->links[$key]`, потому что если вместо него подставить ссылку в виде строки ошибки не будет.

Результат  `var_dump($Habr->links)` :

```
 array(5) { 
      ["infosecurity"]=> string(55) "https://habrahabr.ru/company/kaspersky/blog/348572/ "
     ["programming"]=> string(37) "https://habrahabr.ru/post/348656/ "
     ["webdev"]=> string(52) "https://habrahabr.ru/company/skyeng/blog/348606/ "
     ["linux"]=> string(51) "https://habrahabr.ru/company/flant/blog/348324/ "
    ["algorithms"]=> string(37) "https://habrahabr.ru/post/348530/ " 
 }
```

Comment: зачем вам `links[$key]` если это же самое у вас в `$value` содержится? у вас не синтаксическая ошибка, как вы указали в тэгах, а рантайм. явно написано, что попытка обратиться к свойству у null. приведите блока кода с этой 44й строкой, указанной  в ошибке файла `class.php`

Comment: чую проблема в `get_content` и кто-то там возвращает `null` (`$html`, `$dom` или `$article`)

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста первый блок кода, там внизу есть строка   `return  $article[0]->$type.'<br>';   // строка ошибки`

Comment: а, тогда  `$article` у вас при выполнении этого кода равен `null`, чего то на странице не нашлось, тэга какого то (`$tag`)

Comment: можете подсказать как исправить? и почему при передаче в `$html` строковой ссылки всё нормально?

Comment: пока вы не углубились далеко в дебри парсинга html-контента, я бы предложил вам использовать [RSS](https://habrahabr.ru/rss/hub/infosecurity/)

Comment: сразу так не скажешь, в чем там ошибка. данный метод вызывается два раза. займитесь отладкой, просмотрите параметры, которые туда поступают при возникноквении ошибки. У вас ссылок несколько, а пробуете передать явно вы только одну. проверьте тогда каждую. в одной из них чего нибудь да не будет.